# Is it possible to send ERC usdT without paying gas fees?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, gas, usdt, tether

Is it possible to send ERC usdT without paying gas fees?

I have seen in some crypto site this text:

> If you have an old Tether address, you'll be charged a network fee
> when you use it to deposit Tether. You can avoid that fee by using
> your new Tether address.

Does this mean I can transact with tether on the Ethereum blockchain without paying gas fees? Or what does it mean?

If you can transact without paying gas, how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way skipping gas fees. Even when you send 0 ETH/USDT/USDC you are paying the gas fees.

Comment: You can manually set the gas price to 0, which makes the overall transaction fee also 0. Whether or not a miner decides to mine that transaction into a block is another matter... :-)